# Unit test for upload to S3 file

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am unable to work out unit tests for this s3 upload method in spring boot .Also I am unable to pass S3Client in class constructor as it is Interface

```java
@Service
public class S3Service {
  

  @Value("${aws.endpoint}")
  private String awsEndpoint;


    public void uploadFiletoS3(String S3Key, InputStream inputStream, String S3Bucket, Region region)
            throws  AwsServiceException, SdkClientException, IOException {
        S3Client client = S3Client.builder().endpointOverride(URI.create(awsEndpoint)).region(region).build();

        PutObjectRequest request = PutObjectRequest.builder()
                            .bucket(S3Bucket)
                            .contentType("text/plain")
                            .key(S3Key)
                            .build();
      client.putObject(request,
                RequestBody.fromInputStream(inputStream, inputStream.available()));
        inputStream.close();
    }
}
```